# Unable to load saved position of dropped item from local storage using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to programming; this is my very first question on Stake-overflow.

I want to save the position of the dropped div in local storage and retrieve this position when I refresh the page.

**Here is what I have achieved so far using Javascript:**

1) I can store the position of dropped div in local storage (by calling a function on enddrop event.)

2) I can retrieve the stored position (by calling a function on onload event)

**What I want:**

1) I want to position the dropped div according to retrieved position (position left and top from local storage.)

**Here is my code:**

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body onload="get_pos(event)">

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div style="margin-left:50px;" id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div style="margin-left:100px;" id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"  ondragend="set_pos(event);get_pos(event);" id="drag1">

pTop: <span id="pt"></span> <br>
pLeft: <span id="pl"></span> 
<span style="margin-left:80px;">Drag Me!</span>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
  #div1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
#drag1 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);

}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

}

function set_pos(e) {
  var div = document.getElementById("drag1");
  var rect = div.getBoundingClientRect();
  x = rect.left;
  y = rect.top;

   // Store
  localStorage.setItem("pTop", y);
  localStorage.setItem("pLeft", x);
}

function get_pos(e) {
  var a = localStorage.getItem("pTop");
  var b = localStorage.getItem("pLeft");

  document.getElementById("drag1").style.top = a+"px";

  document.getElementById("drag1").style.left = b+"px";

  document.getElementById("pt").innerHTML = a+"px";

  document.getElementById("pl").innerHTML = b+"px";
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you please fix the jsfiddle link?

Comment: Please refer to this section on [mcve].

Comment: Now, I have added my code.

Comment: The editor has a bracket button: `[<>]` click that then add your code.

Comment: I don't think he can run his code on HTML snippet, cause he's using localStorage features, and I think it's not available

Comment: Yes, I am unable to add code in HTML Snippet, a security related error occurs.

Comment: That's expected, it's just easier to copy your code to my answer. BTW duplicated ids are invalid and can cause unexpected behavior. Instead of 3 `id='div1'` -- do `id='div1'`, `id='div2'`, and `id='div3'`. Or 3 `class='div1'`.

Comment: @SaymoinSam I have changed the div to be dropped to absolute position, but, after that I am unable to again drag the dive.

Comment: If you have an abspos tag then make its parent tag relpos.

Comment: @zer00ne I have tried your suggestion, but after setting draggable div's position to absolute and drop zone to relative or static, the next time I refresh the page, I cannot drag the div to a new position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made it dynamic, you can now drag divs, images, I took care about the order of the dragged elements. now you can modifie it to store in your server instead of the client. happy coding :)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
  <title>Retrieve drag position</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .drop_box {
      width: 100px;
      height: 120px;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 5px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    img, .dragged_box {
      width: 90px;
      height: 30px;
    }
    .red {
      background-color: red;
    }
    .blue {
      background-color: blue;
    }
    .green {
      background-color: green;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body onload="retrieve()">

  <div class="dragged_box red" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag_div1"></div>
  <div class="dragged_box blue" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag_div2"></div>
  <div class="dragged_box green" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag_div3"></div>

  <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/bungalow.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag_img1">
  <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/50/000000/bungalow.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag_img2">
  <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/50/000000/bungalow.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag_img3">

  <div class="drop_box" id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div class="drop_box" id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div class="drop_box" id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div class="drop_box" id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

  <script>
    var draggedImages = {
      draggedIds: [],
      droppedIds: [] 
    }

    function allowDrop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
      ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var id = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");

      if(draggedImages.draggedIds.indexOf(id) === -1) {
        draggedImages.draggedIds.push(id);
        draggedImages.droppedIds.push(ev.target.id);
      }else {
        var ind = draggedImages.draggedIds.indexOf(id);
        // to keep the order of images
        draggedImages.draggedIds.splice(ind, 1);
        draggedImages.droppedIds.splice(ind, 1);
        draggedImages.draggedIds.push(id);
        draggedImages.droppedIds.push(ev.target.id);
      }

      localStorage["draggedImages"] = JSON.stringify(draggedImages);
      ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(id));
    }

    function retrieve() {
      if(localStorage["draggedImages"]) {
        draggedImages = JSON.parse(localStorage["draggedImages"]);

        draggedImages.draggedIds.forEach(function(draggedId, ind) {
          document.getElementById(draggedImages.droppedIds[ind]).appendChild(document.getElementById(draggedId));
        });
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have changed my code as per your answer. After changing to absolute position, the next time I refresh the page, the div cannot be dragged to a new position. Now, my drop zone is static and drageable absolute, but not working..

Comment: Many thanks, I have been trying this for many hours, I think the problem is with setting positions. Waiting for your kindness!

Comment: I have edited the post take a look, I have bad connection this evening sorry :(

Comment: Thank you!. The code you shared works perfectly as is.
Problem:
But when I tested it on div (made div draggable instead of img), it did not work, also if I add more than one img, only the first one works. 
I am a very beginner, the approach you used is different from my code. 
I have to store positions in the database (first storing position in variables then sending values to database) and have to make more than one element draggable. 
I would be grateful, if you help in this regard! I am using Flask as a back-end (but if I get it work on local storage, I can do rest).

Comment: Ok, I have edited the post to solve your problems. you can now accept it as answer :)